# How to transfer files between an Ubuntu machine and Windows machine?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, file-sharing

I have a desktop pc with Ubuntu and a laptop with Windows 7.

I'd like to transfer lots of files and archives from the desktop to the laptop. When I want to share a file, says I should install some Windows stuff and doesn't allow it because it is untrusted. How can I transfer all my data via Ethernet or something similar?

Comment: Do you have admin rights over the Windows 7 computer, or is it a work computer or something similar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can connect both devices via ethernet. when you configure your eth- ports so that they are in the same IP-range (e.g. winows is 192.168.1.1, Ubuntu is 192.168.1.2), you can use Nautilus to access your windows-PC and move or copy your files and directories. Another option would be to use an external USB-drive or a cloud service like Ubuntu One.

Comment: the ethernet-access system won't work unless you have sharing enabled, and samba enabled at that.  Windows doesn't have that on by default.